# installing poppler-data failes on ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, connection, poppler

```
   root@2172269688e3:/# apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt install -y poppler-data
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  poppler-utils ghostscript fonts-japanese-mincho | fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-japanese-gothic | fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-nanum
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  poppler-data
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.      
Need to get 1475 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 poppler-data all 0.4.9-2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler-data/poppler-data_0.4.9-2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

can anyone help me?

thank you!

Comment: Hello. Are you sure you are trying to install from the right location? A quick Google search tells me to get it from here. https://github.com/Distrotech/poppler-data

Comment: Did you try running `sudo apt update` again and then `sudo apt -f install` like it suggested?

Comment: the poppler-data is normaly a dependency form another packages (ghostscript, graphickimages etc.) . how can i change the location for that? i have a complete new installation of ubuntu.

Comment: sudo apt -f install doesnt fix the issue.